# How do I fix a checkbox to a location in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, checkbox

I am attempting to fix a checkbox to a certain cell because, what I believe to be a bug continuously moves it.

I have already tried selecting " Don't move and size with cells" and it will randomly shift to a different location without the re-sizing of any cells.

Others seem to have the same issue but no one has any answers

any help  would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to determine an appropriate event. I picked the BeforeSave event so that the control is always repositioned before it saves. You may want an event that fires more often.

In the event, you can set the Top and Left properties to whatever you want, including to the Top and Left properties of a cell.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    With Sheet1.Shapes("Check Box 1")
        .Top = Sheet1.Range("J3").Top
        .Left = Sheet1.Range("J3").Left
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the speedy response! I'm very new to VBA (Matlab and Swift are more my bread and butter). When I implement this macro(Or at least attempt to) it doesn't seem to do anything upon saving.

I used your code verbatim and also changed .Shapes to .CheckBox1 Both don't throw any errors but both don't move anything upon saving. Can you help me out?

Comment: This code has to go in the ThisWorkbook module. Events can only be in class modules: workbook events go in ThisWorkbook, worksheet events go in the sheet's module, other events go in custom class modules. If you put this in a standard module, it would not trigger.

Comment: This is awesome so far! is there a way to root it to the right side? I essentially want to center these check boxes and its easier if I can link it to the right side.

and one final thing. 

If Someone chooses to insert a row in between two check boxes how could I assign that checkbox to not snap to the  new row/colum before save

Comment: You get Top, Left, Height, and Width. To center or right align, you have to do the math. To right align, for instance, you set Left to (Left minus the difference in widths). For center, it would be half the distance of the widths.

Comment: Instead of using a cell reference like J3 in your code, name a cell and use the named range. If you name J3 to `chkbox1_anchor` and the user enters a new row 3, that name will now point to J4. Then in your code `.Top = Sheet1.Range("chkbox1_anchor").Top` etc.

Comment: First one worked like a charm!



    With Sheet1.Shapes("Check Box 2")
        Range("j4").Name = "MyCell2"
        .Top = Sheet1.Range("MyCell2").Top
        .Left = Sheet1.Range("MyCell2").Left
    End With

This code runs but it doesnt seem to do anything different when a row is inserted. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Is that code in the BeforeSave event? Then it will only run before you save, not when a row is inserted. If you need that to run when a row is inserted, you have to put it in a different event. There is no 'insert row' event, so SheetCalculate is probably your best bet. But beware that it will run *a lot* and may affect performance. It seems that if you made the checkbox `Move and don't size with cells` that it would follow the cell down when a row is inserted. Then you could keep your code in BeforeSave so it doesn't run so often.  You'll have to test it out to see.

Comment: That seems to be my issue though. The cell will move down with the cell and usage goes on as per usual. but when I save it will jump back to the location it is rooted to is there any way to fix this without slaughtering performance.

Comment: That's what the named range does. It moves down also. Don't name the range in code, name it in the UI. If you name it in code, you will always be moving it to, say, J4. But if you name J4 in the UI and only refer to the name in code, then the name will move with inserts and deletes.